# Using Entity Framework Code First CTP5, how do I create a primary key column that are INTs and are not identity columns

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

Using Entity Framework Code First CTP5, how do I create a primary key column that are INTs and are not identity columns

Preferably not using attributes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're building your entities using the fluent interface rather than using attributes over the properties, you may be able to use the DatabaseGenerationOption class (from EntityFramework.dll, in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace). I've not tested it, but this is what it would look like:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Foo>()
    .Property(f => f.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Comment: I hated this API choice, so I wrote these extension methods on PrimitivePropertyConfiguration .Identity(isIdentity:false), and .Computed()

Answer (score 48):

That answer didn't work for me (in EF 4.1).

To make this work, I added DatabaseGenerated attribute to my key column:

```
public class FacebookUser
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public long FacebookId { get; set; }

  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Worked a treat, and had the bonus that the schema declaration was kept within the class declaration, rather than moved out somewhere in the generic build method. Making it more discoverable IMHO.

Comment: I'm not sure why this worked but the fluent API answer by @MattHamilton didn't, but it did. Thanks :)

Comment: just to add this thing doesn't work in case of migrations you have to drop and create db then it works both fluent and annotate cases

Comment: For .Net Framework this is in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace.

Answer (score 12):

Small Change

```
public class User
{

  [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

  public int ID { get; set; }

  // Rest of the code
}
```