# Add object graph to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have an object graph that is created from deserializing json, when calling SaveChanges to I'm getting:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Pickles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Pickles'. The duplicate key value is (P1).
The statement has been terminated.`

I understand why I get the exception but fail to think of a nice way to add the graph.

Below is a small standalone repro of the issue.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tempy
{
    public class DbTests
    {
        private Unicorn _u1 = new Unicorn { Id = "U1" };
        private Unicorn _u2 = new Unicorn { Id = "U2" };
        private Pickle _p1 = new Pickle { Id = "P1" };
        private Pickle _p2 = new Pickle { Id = "P2" };


        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            using (var context = new TempContext())
            {
                if (context.Database.Exists())
                    context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void InsertTest()
        {
            _u1.Pickles.UnionWith(new[] { _p1, _p2 });
            _u2.Pickles.UnionWith(new[] { _p1, _p2 });
            using (var context = new TempContext())
            {
                context.Unicorns.Add(_u1);
                context.Unicorns.Add(_u2);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void InsertFailsTest()
        {
            _u1.Pickles.UnionWith(new[] { _p1, _p2 });
            _u2.Pickles.UnionWith(new[] { new Pickle { Id = _p1.Id }, _p2 });
            using (var context = new TempContext())
            {
                context.Unicorns.Add(_u1);
                context.Unicorns.Add(_u2);
                Assert.Throws<DbUpdateException>(()=>context.SaveChanges()); //Is there a nice way to get this to work?
            }
        }
    }
    public class TempContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Pickle> Pickles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Unicorn> Unicorns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pickle
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        private readonly ISet<Unicorn> _unicorns = new HashSet<Unicorn>();
        public virtual ISet<Unicorn> Unicorns { get { return _unicorns; } }
    }

    public class Unicorn
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        private readonly ISet<Pickle> _pickles = new HashSet<Pickle>();
        public virtual ISet<Pickle> Pickles { get { return _pickles; } }
    }
}
```

Feels like this is a duplicate but I failed to come up with a good search.

Question: what is a nice way to add this graph?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate your id, put this annotation above the ID

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

for more info see  this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999853/using-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-how-do-i-create-a-primary-key-column-tha)

Comment: I think convention handles that out-of-the-box

Comment: By defualt is DatabaseGeneratedOption.None so that mean you have to add the key by your self. I have 3 qusitions here : 1) why your id string and not int or long 2) why you are using ISET and net ICollection 3) why Id and UnicornId

Comment: see this example Many to Many RS:http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/13/many-to-many-relationships-with-ef.aspx

Comment: 1) I get the data from another source and the keys are strings.

2) I'm very noob with ef, is ISet a poor choice?

3) I can't find UnicornId

Comment: copy and paste the example above in my link ...odetocode... and this will work & do it step by step. good luck!

Comment: The `InsertTest` works and creates many-to-many I think. My question is how to make `InsertFailsTest` work in a nice way. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi the second test InsertFailsTest looking very correct you have one assertion 100% unity but the InsertTest you have forget i think the assertion. You are talking about graph you mean object graph from Entity Framework?  You can catch the DBUpdateException and wrap the excepition with another one give the innerexception info.  I hope this will help you.