# How to manually set entity primary key in Entity Framework code first database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key

Well, I have the following model structure: I have one class - `DatabaseEntity` which is basically

```
public class DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

so each entity like product, category etc will inherit `DatabaseEntity` and have `Id` property. Also I have typical `EntityFramework` repository class with `InsertOrUpdate` method:

```
private readonly DbContext _database;

public void InsertOrUpdate<TObject>(TObject entity) where TObject : DatabaseEntity
{
    if(entity.Id == default(int))
    {
         // New entity
         DbSet<TObject>().Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
         // Existing entity
         _database.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then I download from eBay via eBay api list of categoies I have to add to database. Basically category is:

```
public class EbayCategory : DatabaseEntity
{
    // It has Id since it inherits DatabaseEntity
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    // ... some other properties
}
```

But, the problem is, when I download those categories I download and their Id properties, which, of course, already have values. And when I try to save them to database like:

```
public void UpdateCategories(IEnumerable<EbayCategory> newCategories)
{
    foreach (var newCategory in newCategories)
    {
        _repository.InsertOrUpdate(newCategory);
    }
}
```

I face some issues... First of all, `entity.Id != default(int)` because it has value, so repository tries to update this entity, instead of adding, but it is not in the database or context so it throws the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurencyException
"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."
```

... because it thinks that someone else deleted entity which I am trying to update. How can I save this InsertOrUpdate logic, since a lot of projects are based on it, and be able to add items (`EbayCategories`) with primary key (`Id`) to database and then update/delete them like other entities without discarding `EbayCategory.Id` value?

Comment: Do you need the Id value? Why not discarding it and let sql server generate a new Id via Identity?

Comment: @RosdiKasim, Yes, I NEED that Id value.

Comment: And how is the Id situation for your other classes?

Comment: I don't see any way you can do this WITHOUT modifying your `InsertOrUpdate` method.

Comment: You could change your method to check in the database first, as in querying by id  and if the item is there, update, else insert. However, if there are a lot of items this could get expensive.

Comment: @RickDailey, this is not an option since there are about 6000 categories i need to add and later update.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, in other classes there is no need in specific id value.

Comment: When the primary-key requirements are very different from the other classes it shouldn't inherit from the same base class.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that'd be a problem.  You could look into this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 11):

To allow you to manually generate Ids you need a class that has a manually generated ID - so it cannot inherit from `DatabaseEntity`

```
public class EbayCategory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }      
    // ... some other properties
}
```

Now you will need a different `InsertOrUpdate` to handle entities that have manually generated keys:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(EbayCategory entity)
{
    if(Find(entity.ID == null)
    {
         // New entity
         DbSet<EbayCategory>().Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
         // Existing entity
         _database.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Colin's answer above quite correctly shows how to achieve this setting using data annotations. 
But in the presented problem the entity is a subclass so you can't add the annotation without changing the entity class.

There is an alternative configuration method: Fluent Configuration. Here's my example using an EntityTypeConfiguration class:

```
public class LookupSchoolsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LookupSchools>
    {
        public LookupSchoolsConfiguration()
        {
            Property(l => l.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        }
    }
```

You can also add configuration directly to the modelBuilder as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999894/486028