# Excess context saving (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework

Help me please resolve one problem.
I use Entity Framework for work with datebase.

My situation:
I have two tables which i need to fill. One of them must to contain identificator from the second table. Now I insert data to first table and make save changes. It give me identificator for the entity and I can to insert in second table the row with this identificator from first entity.

As a result, I have two save changes for my context. And I think that it's bad practice.

Code example:

```
        var registration = new Registration()
        {
            //fill some properties
        };
        _registrationEntityService.Insert(registration);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var profile = new Profile()
        {
            //fill some properties
            profile.RegId = registration.Id
        };

        _profileEntityService.Insert(profile);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

How I can resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your implementation code so it will be easier to solve the problem. Of course welcome to StackOverflow! Please start with [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Especially useful code to see would be your entities, your configuration, and where you create and save.

Comment: Sure. I added code example.

Comment: @A.Bruilo Can you include your entity definitions as well? Specifically, do you have navigation properties between Registration and Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF assumes to use navigation properties like `profile.Registration` to resolve such problems:

```
var registration = new Registration()
{
    //fill some properties
};

var profile = new Profile()
{
    //fill some properties
    profile.Registration = registration
};

context.SaveChanges();
```

Just ensure you generated the needed navigation property (it's generally based on foreign keys in your db). I highly recommend you to read any EF guide first http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/add-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: Unless there are no navigation properties, in which case he'd be restricted to using the IDs as he currently does

Comment: What about case when I can't do navigation property? (because i have not foreign keys between tables and don't have opportunity for add this)

Comment: First option is, as @Vlad274 wrote, to keep your current strategy (simple!). The second one is to generate IDs on EF side, but it is much more complicated and error-prone way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005451/how-to-manually-set-entity-primary-key-in-entity-framework-code-first-database